# Web2py or Grails frames for project

Tags: grails, web2py

I'm going to start new project, not so big(not enterparise). and I don't know which of this frames is good. main points of choosing are the ease codding and server price when I'll host the project. I know java well, and some grails. but my python is not so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to consider here:

- You will be most productive with what you already know, which would indicate Grails
- You need to research hosting costs - Java-capable hosting is typically more expensive, but not always so. For instance, if it's something relatively small, and non-commercial, you could host a Grails app on Heroku for free.
- Are Groovy and Python the only languages that you know? And are these the best/only frameworks available for each? You haven't indicated whether you have considered the possibilities, and narrowed it down to these two language/framework combinations, or if they are merely the ones with which you are most familiar. If the former, great. If the latter, you may want to do a bit more research before deciding.

Comment: u right, I know java and grails much better and after some surfing in internet I understand, that grails is good choise for this project.